# About Visibility in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

**Context**

For an exam (that I've now passed) I was making an OO program in C# that handled runners joining races. Racers could edit their own details, join races, buy merchandise, pay race fees, stuff like that.

Since I'm now going to university next year, I've decided to improve my practices and make a simple modular library I can use for future projects.

**Problem**

The main issue my program had in particular was *view model* code, especially stuff like this:

[image: Visibility Modifiers]

The use of this code was to collapse inputs upon a button press, to prevent users from editing these containers outwith the edit method.

but in my opinion, this is really messy code, but I have no idea how to get rid of code like this. I have this in multiple different areas of my program.